# Android App is not visible in playstore after facebook ad integration

Tags: android, facebook, google-play-services, facebook-ads-api

I integrate facebook ads in android app for promoting my app on facebook. after that
My android app successfully publish on playstore. 
after 24 hours, my android app invisible from play store. when i enter playstore url of my app then app is visible on playstore. 
Why app not seen when i write by its name on playstore?

Comment: same name have lot of app so your app is not coming first on list.

Comment: thank you for your point of view but this is not issue here because app is visible on  playstore through https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="myapp" this link.

Comment: please give your app package name

Comment: Hi @Pratik18, Thank for interest. Issue successfully solved. This is happen due to i generated wrong Facebook key hash. That's why App is not visible on playstore. Once i create Facebook key hash using SHA1 from playstore then i create new key hash and update it on facebook. After 2 hour it was visible on playstore.